# dismissModalViewControllerAnimated works but not releasing memory (ARC enabled )

Tags: iphone, automatic-ref-counting

Please see below sample . Every thing works but memory is not released. Here MYTest is not getting released and memory seems to be increasing when watched in instruments tool

```
- (IBAction)methodXYZ:(id)sender
{

        MYTest * myTest = [[MYTest alloc]initWithNibName:@"myNib" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: myTest];
        [self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
    }
}
```

and in myTest when finished i call

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

i also tried setting delegate and dismissing from parent , but that also doesnt solve the issue ..

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
mia

Comment: Just create a properties of myTest and test. i guess it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If ARC is enabled (be sure it is) you dont need to worry about it, the system will dealloc the memory when it's necessary.

In the other hand, I invite you to take a look at the classic way (non ARC), its useful sometimes if you want to have a control of the memory like it seems you want.

Comment: I don't see why people seem to think that with ARC you have no control over memory management. You do. It's *not* garbage collection remember - reference counting is still going on.